# Как записать звук с out (динамики и т.д.)?

Tags: android

Я знаю, что как один из вариантов для записи звука можно использовать 
`MediaCodec`, но он ему для записи нужны байты.

Для того, чтоб получить байты можно использовать `AudioRecord` и инициализировать его вот так

```
new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat, minBufferSize * 4)
```

Но таким образом он будет получать байты с микрофона. Возможность поменять `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` на динамики нет.

Набор возможных констант вот такой

```
    public static final int CAMCORDER = 5;
    public static final int DEFAULT = 0;
    public static final int MIC = 1;
    public static final int REMOTE_SUBMIX = 8;
    public static final int UNPROCESSED = 9;
    public static final int VOICE_CALL = 4;
    public static final int VOICE_COMMUNICATION = 7;
    public static final int VOICE_DOWNLINK = 3;
    public static final int VOICE_PERFORMANCE = 10;
    public static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION = 6;
    public static final int VOICE_UPLINK = 2;
```

Так вот вопрос, как получить звук с динамика?

Comment: Не походит ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959930/android-need-to-record-mic-input

Comment: @Alexander нет, там вопрос о том как записать звук с микрофона, а у меня вопрос как записать с динамика

Comment: Интересную задачу вы себе придумали! Что значит с динамиков? вы хотите записывать то что на пример воспроизводит система или реально запись с физических динамиков?

Comment: Автор вопроса , как раз имеет в виду захват сигнала, который идёт на динамик нашего смартфона. Меня это тоже интересует, вот сам искал ответ, надеюсь поможет кто.